# How to replace last digit of a string with bracket

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

How to replace last digit of a string with bracket

Consider a table having column A

```
A
-------
12345
123455
123567
1234
```

Expected result:

```
1234(5)
12345(5)
12356(7)
123(4)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help for the alignment.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two options:

- one using `substr`,
- another regular expressions

---

```
SQL> with test (a) as
  2    (select 12345  from dual union all
  3     select 1234   from dual union all
  4     select 123567 from dual
  5    )
  6  select a,
  7         substr(a, 1, length(a) - 1) || '(' || substr(a, -1) || ')' result,
  8         regexp_replace(a, '(.)$', '(\1)') result2
  9  from test;

         A RESULT               RESULT2
---------- -------------------- --------------------
     12345 1234(5)              1234(5)
      1234 123(4)               123(4)
    123567 12356(7)             12356(7)

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi, I have checked with your code, it is really working fine. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, user-with-many-digits; thank you, @Wernfried :)